# Problem to update mongoose schema in post request using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, express, post, mongoose

I have the problem that when I make a post request to my schema it does not store the new values in the episodes array.

Using postman in the body I added the new data, I mean new anime content, but that content is not added to the array of episodes. In total there are 25 episodes but with the new content it is supposed to increase to 26.

Any help will be appreciated.

**This is my body in POSTMAN**

```
   "url": "https: \ / \ / www.crunchyroll.com \ / 07-ghost \ / episode-26-the-heart-is-lead-by-the-truth-on-the-othe-side-578512 ",
   "description": "Teito uses the power of the Eye of Mikhail to summon Frau, Castor, Labrador, Lance, and the Black Hawks.",
   "episode_number": "26",
   "thumbnail": "https: \ / \ / www.facebook.com \ / tr? id = 2107366626037622 & ev = PageView & noscript = 1",
   "name": "07 Ghost Episode 26"
}
```

**Schema**

```
"episodes": {
    "1x": {
      "07 Ghost": [{
          "url": "https:\/\/www.crunchyroll.com\/07-ghost\/episode-25-the-heart-is-lead-by-the-truth-on-the-other-side-578512",
          "description": "Teito uses the power of the Eye of Mikhail to summon Frau, Castor, Labrador, Lance, and the Black Hawks.",
          "episode_number": "25",
          "thumbnail": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/tr?id=2107366626037622&ev=PageView&noscript=1",
          "name": "07 Ghost Episode 25"
        },
```

**POST REQUEST**

```
// Update the "Episodes" array in the DB when a JSON is sent via "POST" request.
router.post('/series/:id/post' , (req , res , next) =>{
  let id = req.params.id;
  SeriesModel.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: new ObjectID(id)
  },{
    $push: {
    "episodes.${'1x'}.${'07 Ghost'}": {
        "url": req.body.url,
        "description": req.body.description,
        "episode_number": req.body.episode_number,
        "thumbnail": req.body.thumbnail, 
        "name": req.body.name,
      }
    }
  }, 
  {new: true}, (err, result) => {
    if(err){ 
      console.error('error to update episodes')
    }else{
      console.log("episode section updated" , result)
    }
 }).then(result =>{
   console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Handling POST request to episodes",
      episode: result
    })
 }).catch(err =>{
   res.status(500).json({error: err})
 })
})
```

This is the output after POST REQUEST in the terminal

```
POST /api/v1/animes/series/5d454473084e0306452caa12/post 200 929.910 ms - 19844
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`

� Listening: http://localhost:8081
episode section updated { aggregateRating:
   { reviewCount: 100,
     ratingCount: 1387,
     '@type': 'AggregateRating',
     ratingValue: 4.7 },
  episodes: { '1x': { '07 Ghost': [Array] } },
  metadata:
   { description:
      'Teased unmercifully for his past as an orphan and a slave, Teito has only his best friend Mikage and his mastery of the magical art of Zaiphon to ease his days at the elite Barsburg Academy.',
     url: 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/07-ghost',
     image:
      'https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4/1d3f1855ba933617b4d6792d9d3154191300831088_full.jpg',
     type: 'TVSeries',
     id: 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/07-ghost',
     name: '07 Ghost' },
  '1x':
   { '07 Ghost':
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  _id: 5d454473084e0306452caa12,
  series_id: 'GYWE4X28Y',
  __v: 0 }
POST /api/v1/animes/series/5d454473084e0306452caa12/post 200 740.518 ms - 19844
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`

� Listening: http://localhost:8081
episode section updated { aggregateRating:
   { reviewCount: 100,
     ratingCount: 1387,
     '@type': 'AggregateRating',
     ratingValue: 4.7 },
  episodes: { '1x': { '07 Ghost': [Array] } },
  metadata:
   { description:
      'Teased unmercifully for his past as an orphan and a slave, Teito has only his best friend Mikage and his mastery of the magical art of Zaiphon to ease his days at the elite Barsburg Academy.',
     url: 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/07-ghost',
     image:
      'https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4/1d3f1855ba933617b4d6792d9d3154191300831088_full.jpg',
     type: 'TVSeries',
     id: 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/07-ghost',
     name: '07 Ghost' },
  '1x':
   { '07 Ghost':
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  _id: 5d454473084e0306452caa12,
  series_id: 'GYWE4X28Y',
  __v: 0 }
```

According to postman the update was successful
`"message": "Handling POST request to episodes"`

You can see in the episode arrangement, continue with the 25 episodes and not with 26 that is supposed to happen.
[image]

Comment: There's not much to go on here. Please be more specific about the return result. Is there an error? If so, what is it? If not, then what is the returned result? We need to know this kind of information if we're going to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @B.Fleming I just added more information, which may be helpful.

Comment: @B.Fleming I realized in Postman that when I execute the POST request, what he is doing to me is technically to make a copy of the whole scheme but with 25 episodes and not 26;